# MATLAB How to Use URLREAD with a Password Protected Website

Tags: matlab, password-protection, urlread

I am trying to use `urlread` to grab the contents of a password protected website. When I'm logged in, the url is http://media.nba.com/Stats/OfficialBoxScores.aspx, and when logged out, the url is http://media.nba.com/Stats/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fStats%2fOfficialBoxScores.aspx. I've tried

`urlread('http://media.nba.com/Stats/OfficialBoxScores.aspx','Username','username','Password','password');`

with my login credentials but it only gives me the contents of the url before logging in. I see that this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find a solution for my situation. Is there a way to use `urlread` to get past the password protection wall?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Imitate POST request, submitting the data from the form with username and password, get response with cookies, use those cookies with every further request. But this is not what Matlab was created for. Why not to use something external, like `wget`, for example?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to integrate this code into an existing MATLAB script. I'm very much so a MATLAB novice and have even less experience with pulling data from the web. Could the `wget` method be integrated into MATLAB code using the `system` function or in some other way?

Comment: It is not a method - external console program. The main problem here is to keep and use cookies with every request - they might have session ID which identifies you as logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `method` (use 'post'), and the parameters need to be a cell array of name/value pairs.

Does this work :

```
urlread('http://media.nba.com/Stats OfficialBoxScores.aspx','post',{'Username','username';'Password','password'} );
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's still pulling the code from the login page

Answer (score 0):

```
%Allows you to access url that requires username and password

url_login = 'https://www.your-website-loginpage'
url_data = 'https://www.your-website-data-url'
[stat,h] = web(url_login) %Enter username and password in the popup
setCurrentLocation(h, url_data)
pageText = h.getHtmlText()
```